# package "makeR" is not available (for version 3.0.2)

Tags: r

I'm new with R, and I'm doing a kind of "how to start at data analysis with R", and that's one part that I need to install  `makeR`, but it gives the error of version.
Does anyone know what might be happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**makeR** is no longer supported and has been removed from CRAN (see this [link](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/makeR/index.html)).

[R-Studio](http://www.rstudio.com/ide/docs/packages/overview) has some tools, such as git integration, that pick up some the functionality of **makeR**.